# Let $V$ be the collection of all functions $f \colon E \to\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and find a basis of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given that $E=\{1,2,..n\}$ and $f,g \in V$ satisfy:

1) $(f+g)(k)=f(k)+g(k),  \forall k\in  E$

2) $(cf)(k)=cf(k), c \in \mathbb{R} $

Proving it is a vector space is easy. However, I didn't understand how the mapping is defined. Also since this is a set of functions will not the basis be infinte dimensional? I have not yet learnt to find a basis for inifnite dimensional vector spaces. 
Please explain to be how any mapping $f \colon E \to\mathbb{R}^2$ works. Someone suggested to me that $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Is that right? Why?

Comment: The dimension is $2n$.  The value of $f$ at $k$ is an ordered pair, so you associate a $2\times n$-matrix with $f$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Then a basis is given by $f_i(x)=\begin{cases} 

(a_i,0) \text {if}\ x=i \\

 (0,0) \text {otherwise},\\ 
\end{cases} i=1(1)n$ and
 $f_j(x)=\begin{cases} 
(0,a_j) \text {if}\ x=j \\

 (0,0)\ \text {otherwise}\\ \end{cases}\ j=1(1)n \\$

$\\ a_i, a_j \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Oops, forgot to add. $a_i, a_j \neq 0$

Comment: Another typo in the range of $j$, it should be $j=n(1)2n$.

Comment: Well, a basis is the set of matrices which contain exactly one $1$ and all other elements are zero.